# Convert INT to VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server-2008

All,

I have a populated table with the column '**SSN**' as data type **INT**.  Is it is possible to convert the column '**SSN**', and the data within the column, to VARCHAR(#)'s.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
 MODIFY SSN varchar(9);
```

Will that work?

Thank you!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
alter table Table1
  alter column SSN varchar(9);
```

You can do a quick test to verify this will preserve the data.

```
create table #data(
  ssl int
)

insert into #data values(1)
insert into #data values(2)
insert into #data values(3)
insert into #data values(4)

select * from #data

alter table #data
  alter column ssl varchar(9)

select * from #data
```

And it never hurts to have backups before doing things like this.  Even a quick insert into another table works if it's not a huge amount of data.

Comment: Will this convert the data in the column to varchar's and preserve the data?

Comment: I'd recommend rebuilding your clustered index (or the table in  the case of a heap) after this since your data pages will be fragmented pretty heavily.

Comment: @evglynn : try it on a test database and you will have your answer within seconds rather than waiting for an answer.

Comment: I'm just worried I'll lose the data in the column.  We will be rebuilding the table soon, but I need to see if a string will function.  In this case, will it convert the values to varchar's as desired?

Comment: Yes, it will preserve the data. Always a good idea to back things up first though.

Comment: Generally it is good practise to test on some test database before you apply it on production. These kind of things are really easy to test on your own, rather than asking it online (if it doesn't work, then you should maybe use a search engine or ask the question).

Comment: (1) check first for any values exceeding 9 characters (999,999,999), (2) you'll have to factor in leading zeroes (if SSNs can begin with zeros), and (3) if it's **always** nine characters, make it char, not varchar.

Comment: @Dave Carlile,  I would add this to the end of the test script to verify the column data type:
exec tempdb..sp_help '#data';

Answer (score 2):

For those who need MySQL syntax rather than ANSI SQL syntax, try something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 MODIFY SSN varchar(9)
```

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't allow you to change column type if you have the data already present in it. You can take backup of data and then repopulate the table once it is altered.

Comment: Its not true we can use `Alter table test
Alter column id varchar(10)` and no see any problem.

Comment: Indeed your answer is just not true.